# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs

I am trying to develop a web application using AngularJS. I am not able to route the web pages using ngRoute. I have written web server in Bottle python framework, which throws no error on this part. The browser console shows this straneg error which I am not able to debug saying "RangeError: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded". Following are the code snippets and console stack trace.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('tslApp', ['ngRoute','datatables','ngCookies']);

app.constant('AUTH_EVENTS', {
      loginSuccess: 'auth-login-success',
      loginFailed: 'auth-login-failed',
      logoutSuccess: 'auth-logout-success',
      sessionTimeout: 'auth-session-timeout',
      notAuthenticated: 'auth-not-authenticated',
      notAuthorized: 'auth-not-authorized'
})

app.run(function ($rootScope,$location,AUTH_EVENTS,$cookieStore,$http,$q,$timeout) {
    $rootScope.flag = false;
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
        $cookieStore.get(AUTH_EVENTS);
        if($rootScope.AUTH_EVENTS != AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess && !$cookieStore.get(AUTH_EVENTS)){    
            //console.log($rootScope.AUTH_EVENTS);
            $location.path('/');
            //$route.reload();
        }
        if(absNewUrl.$$route.originalPath == '/dashboard' && $rootScope.flag == false){
            $rootScope.flag = true;
        }
            //here you can check for your own condition and if not logged in then set $location.path(loginpath);
      });
});
```

route.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : '/assets/app/partials/login.html',
            controller : 'loginCtrl'
        })         
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl : '/assets/app/partials/main.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

loginCtrl.js

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', 'loginFactory', function($scope, $rootScope, loginFactory) {
    $(function() {
        $('#toggle-login').click(function() {
            $('#login').toggle();
        });
    })
    $scope.errormessage = new Object();
    $scope.successMessage = new Object();
    $scope.errormessage.isError = false;
    $scope.successMessage.isSuccess = false;
    $rootScope.AUTH_EVENTS = "auth-not-authorized";
    $scope.login = function(credentials) {
        console.log(credentials);
        loginFactory.login(credentials);
    }
}])
```

loginFactory.js

```
app.factory('loginFactory', ['$http', '$q','$rootScope','AUTH_EVENTS' ,'$location','$cookieStore', function ($http,$q,$rootScope,AUTH_EVENTS,$location,$cookieStore) {
    var loginData = {};

    loginData.login = function(credentials) {
        var $promise = $http.post('/login', credentials); //send data to server.py
        $promise.then(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            if (msg.data == 'success') {
                $rootScope.AUTH_EVENTS = AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess;
                $cookieStore.put(AUTH_EVENTS, AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
                $location.path('/dashboard');
            } else {
                $rootScope.AUTH_EVENTS = AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed;
                scope.errormessage.isError = true;
                scope.errormessage.msg = "Wrong username and password";
                console.log("failed 1");
            }
        }, function() {
            $rootScope.AUTH_EVENTS = AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed;
            console.log("failed 2");
        });
    }
    return loginData;
}])
```

console.output and errors:

```
Object {username: "cdcd", password: "cdcdc"}
loginFactory.js:7 Object {data: "success", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
angular.js:11383 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular.js:8127:30)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular.js:7637:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular.js:6993:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular.js:6996:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular.js:6996:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular.js:6996:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular.js:6872:30)
    at link (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular-route.min.js:7:388)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular.js:8125:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:7000/assets/js/angular.js:7637:11) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11383(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8459invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8127nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664
VM101:1122 <error>InjectedScript._isHTMLAllCollection @ VM101:1122InjectedScript.isPrimitiveValue @ VM101:285InjectedScript.RemoteObject @ VM101:1251InjectedScript._wrapObject @ VM101:387InjectedScript.wrapObject @ VM101:298(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11383(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8459invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8127nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7011controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:7664v @ angular-route.js:865link @ angular-route.js:831invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6993compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:6996publicLinkFn @ angular.js:6872link @ angular-route.js:915invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8125
5VM101:1122 <error>
```

Answer (score 3):

This error usually occurs when there is a route loop created at the below code

```
app.run(function ($rootScope,$location,AUTH_EVENTS,$cookieStore,$http,$q,$timeout) {
$rootScope.flag = false;
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
    $cookieStore.get(AUTH_EVENTS);
    if($rootScope.AUTH_EVENTS != AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess && !$cookieStore.get(AUTH_EVENTS)){    
        //console.log($rootScope.AUTH_EVENTS);
        $location.path('/');
        //$route.reload();
    }
    if(absNewUrl.$$route.originalPath == '/dashboard' && $rootScope.flag == false){
        $rootScope.flag = true;
    }
        //here you can check for your own condition and if not logged in then set $location.path(loginpath);
  });
});
```

You might be redirecting to a route from loginfactory and due to some condition it is being processed again and again at $routeChangeStart  event

Comment: I don't see such a looping happen seeing the code. In the loginFactory, based on the server message 'success', I am changing the route using $location.path to '/dashboard' which I have mentioned as a route in route.js . But it does not move to the page assigned as template with this route. Can you pin point me the error where according to you may be the loop occurence?

Comment: Are you able to land on the home page with route "/"?If yes are there any errors in console?

Comment: While being on the route '/', there are no errors on the console.

Comment: Still I dont have a clear ans to it.we'll have to debug it.Add a breakpoint at both the if blocks and check if they are excuted again and again.I'm sure it is something related with the routechangestate event only.(Just for information,rootscope is cleared when you refresh the app by yourself Make sure that you are not checking any such scenario)